# C# - Convert ARGB Color to RGB555

Tags: c#, .net, colors, converters, bit-shift

I have an algorithm that converts RGB555 values to a System.Drawing.Color object;

```
public static Color ToColor(ushort color)
{
    int a = color & 0x8000;
    int r = color & 0x7C00;
    int g = color & 0x03E0;
    int b = color & 0x1F;
    int rgb = (r << 9) | (g << 6) | (b << 3);

    return Color.FromArgb((a * 0x1FE00) | rgb | ((rgb >> 5) & 0x070707));
}
```

A friend wrote this method for me <s>(bitwise shifting is a bit over my head)</s>, what would be the most efficient way to reverse this code?

Thanks for any advice, I've been trying to find an answer for a few days, so any insight would be a breath of fresh air!

*EDIT*

This problem has been solved for a while, but I thought I'd come back and update my post with the final results - Thanks to all who answered!

```
public struct Color555 : IEquatable<Color555>, IComparable<Color555>, IEquatable<ushort>, IComparable<ushort>
{
    public static readonly Color555 MinValue = ushort.MinValue;
    public static readonly Color555 MaxValue = ushort.MaxValue;

    private readonly ushort _Value;

    public Color555(Color value)
    {
        uint c = (uint)value.ToArgb();
        _Value = (ushort)(((c >> 16) & 0x8000 | (c >> 9) & 0x7C00 | (c >> 6) & 0x03E0 | (c >> 3) & 0x1F));
    }

    public Color555(ushort value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj is ushort && Equals((ushort)obj)) || (obj is Color555 && Equals((Color555)obj));
    }

    public bool Equals(ushort other)
    {
        return _Value == other;
    }

    public bool Equals(Color555 other)
    {
        return _Value == other._Value;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Color555 other)
    {
        return _Value.CompareTo(other._Value);
    }

    public int CompareTo(ushort other)
    {
        return _Value.CompareTo(other);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}", _Value);
    }

    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return String.Format(format, _Value);
    }

    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return String.Format(provider, "{0}", _Value);
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return String.Format(provider, format, _Value);
    }

    public int ToArgb()
    {
        return ToColor().ToArgb();
    }

    public Color ToColor()
    {
        int a = _Value & 0x8000;
        int r = _Value & 0x7C00;
        int g = _Value & 0x03E0;
        int b = _Value & 0x1F;
        int rgb = (r << 9) | (g << 6) | (b << 3);

        return Color.FromArgb((a * 0x1FE00) | rgb | ((rgb >> 5) & 0x070707));
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Color555 l, Color555 r)
    {
        return l.Equals(r);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Color555 l, Color555 r)
    {
        return !l.Equals(r);
    }

    public static implicit operator Color555(Color value)
    {
        return new Color555(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator Color555(ushort value)
    {
        return new Color555(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator ushort(Color555 value)
    {
        return value._Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about [`ToArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb.aspx)

Comment: The first step would be to understand it. If you can't grasp bit shifting, and don't have the desire to do so, you don't deserve to be using this code.

Comment: You are aware that you can't get back the exact data since you're throwing away data right?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart is right. Take the overall idea that you're trying to accomplish and don't over complicate it. Color's aren't hard to figure out in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @Chase Florell - I'm looking to convert ARGB to RGB555, the method I posted already does what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart - I don't recall saying anything about not wanting to learn, hence stating any advice towards understanding it would be a breath of fresh air - not like I'm expecting someone to come along and do it for me. I'm not just some copy-paste developer, it just so happens that I've finally needed to ask a question on a public website after 10 years of figuring things out for myself.

Comment: Actually, after re-reading @JonathonReinhart's comment, I'd like to rescind my up-vote. I miss-read "don't diserve to be using this code" with, "should consider something else".... to be honest, I didn't read past the first line. My bad. I think there are many ways to skin a cat, and if you're willing to learn, that's awesome. I will say that since your method is using `FromArgb`, then it's logical that the reverse should be `ToArgb`. I don't have my IDE in front of me to mess with it, but it should be an ok starting point.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell After re-reading my own comment, I agree it was a bit harsh. Too often on this site are 1-rep users asking "plz give me the codes" questions. But my general message is the same: The first step reversing this algorithm would be to understand it. You say that "bitwise shifting is a bit over my head" - so I think the first step would be to understand binary numbers and bit-shifting. Then you'll see that function is extracting 5-bit numbers from the 16-bit input. You haven't really shown any effort in this question, which spurred my frustrated comment.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - I completely understand your frustration, I understand how bitwise shifting works, but when I try to put pen to paper, the numbers confuse me. I'm extremely willing to learn though, it just takes a little longer than most when it comes to math.

Comment: When you say "reverse this code", what do you mean? Would you only be providing Colors that were the result of this code, or would you want a function that dealt with all Colors? In the latter case, you need to also think about how you want to handle colors that don't map exactly.

Comment: @jswolf19 - The desired result would be to have Color555 be a mediator between UInt16 and System.Drawing.Color - Ex. var c = new Color555(Color.Green);
I say 'reverse' because it is essentially the opposite to the 'ToColor' method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Color` uses 32 bits per pixel: 8 bits each for the alpha, red, green, and blue values. (This means that the values for each component can range from 0 to 255.)

A [RGB555](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390989.aspx) color uses 5 bits per pixel (and has no alpha channel), so red, green and blue can each take a value from 0-31.

To convert from one to the other, we need to map the values 0-255 on to the values 0-31. This will obviously be a lossy process; we simply can't represent every possible `Color` and many different `Color` values will be mapped to the same `Color555`.

The simplest mapping is just truncation, where we divide by 8 and discard the remainder. This maps 0-7 to 0, 8-15 to 1, ..., 248-255 to 31. This can be written as a rightwards bitshift by three bits.

We then need to combine the values into a single 16-bit value, which is accomplished by shifting the red and green components to the left.

(Your sample code appears to be setting the alpha channel based on the high bit, so we can convert the alpha channel backwards in the same manner. In this case, we need to map 256 possible values on to 2: 0 or 1. I've chosen to divide the alpha channel exactly in half; there are other possible mappings.)

Putting it all together, it should look like:

```
public Color555(Color color)
{
    _Value = (ushort) ((color.A >= 128 ? 0x8000 : 0x0000) |
        ((color.R & 0xF8) << 7) | ((color.G & 0xF8) << 2) | (color.B >> 3));
}
```

Comment: The code provided seems to be using the most significant bit as an alpha flag, for what it's worth.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use this?

```
{
    Color c = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#555");
    string s = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to take a good look at the ColorTranslator, thanks for sharing that. But looking at documentation, I'm notsure if it would produce the desired results - will have to do some testing.

Comment: [RGB 555](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390989(v=vs.85).aspx) is very VERY different from `...Html('#555');`

Comment: @user2203880 take a look at this link for some quality info on what you're trying to do.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390989(v=vs.85).aspx